# How much heap space does a java reference take?

Tags: java, memory, jvm

An int takes 4 bytes for almost all platforms. How about a Java reference?

```
Map<String, String> m = null;
```

The variable m takes how much space for 32bit/64bit JVM?

```
byte[] b = new byte[10];
```

The byte array above takes 10 bytes, but how much extra space does the reference to b take?
I think b at least includes an address and a length can anyone give me detail?

Comment: If the reference isn't in the heap it takes zero heap space.

Answer (score 10):

A reference in an object uses 4 bytes on most JVMs (whether it is 32 or 64 bit) as recent 64-bit JVMs use [Compressed Oops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#compressedOop) for up to 32-GB of heap   On some 64-bit JVMs it take 8 bytes.

However, the size on the stack is usually not counted, only the heap size matters and in this case it take no size on the heap.

The `byte[10]` actually uses ~24 bytes as it includes a header of 8-12 bytes and an object is allocated on an 8 byte boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the question literally, on most JVMs, all references on 32-bit JVMs take 4 bytes, one 64-bit JVMs, a reference takes 8 bytes.

Comment: If your JVM uses Compressed Oops, your references will be 32-bit on a 64-bit JVM. This is the default on recent JVMs.

Answer (score 0):

According to the spec given, there is no constrain about the memory of reference variable it is up to the developers of J.V.M they may use 32 bits on 32 bit computer,32 or 64 bits on 64 bit computer it all depends up on the jvm programmer